# Encrypted String?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, encryption, c#

(I made a topic but I was ask'd to re-made it)

Hi! I have a program and when I want to decompile/dissamble it finish and when I inspect the code everywhere where should be some filenames there are .(xxxxxxx)

A string example:

```
string[] strArrays = new string[] { .(724934127), .(724937998), .(724937298), .(724933662), .(724933645), .(724936743), .(724933692), .(724933676), .(724933726), .(724933696), .(724933746), .(724933730), .(724933791), .(724937480), .(724933761), .(724933821), .(724933805), .(724933840), .(724933839), .(724933887), .(724933868), .(724931357), .(724931342), .(724931388), .(724931368), .(724931363), .(724931415), .(724937065), .(724931448), .(724931434), .(724931482), .(724931469), .(724931517), .(724931499), .(724938544), .(724931547), .(724931531), .(724931582), .(724931567), .(724938934), .(724931101), .(724938572), .(724931078), .(724931127), .(724940776), .(724937657), .(724931160), .(724940554), .(724938456), .(724936855), .(724931149), .(724931186), .(724936788), .(724931227), .(724937236), .(724931203), .(724931249), .(724931247), .(724931293), .(724931275), .(724931323), .(724931305), .(724931303), .(724930838), .(724930873), .(724930869), .(724930853), .(724930902), .(724930885), .(724930932), .(724930918), .(724930962), .(724930945), .(724931005), .(724930985), .(724930983), .(724931016), .(724931011), .(724931070), .(724931054), .(724930579)
```

There should be something like:

```
string[] array = new string[]{filename.dll, cheat.dll, hack_name, and so on...};
```

How I can make it "readable" ? Thanks!

(Sorry if I did break somehow the rules :/)

Comment: Maybe a better start for you would have been taking the [tour] on signing up. Read the [help] for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: check if there's no decrypt method somewhere near those strings

Comment: I don't think so.. I don't know.. and if I press that dot (from .(xxxxxx)) it moves me to another module (http://paste.org.ru/?cr0e3k if you wonder what module) I'am tottaly lost..

Comment: negative numbers? they look very similar, anyway, it should be easier discovering the code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, to be honest.

Comment: What are those numbers? Are they possibly (quite simply) the *address* where those expected strings are stored?

Comment: I don't know exactly, just I know that in that place for example .(724934127) should be filename.dll -- I don't know how to see it.. (here is the code: http://paste.org.ru/?0neyqg that I need to "uncrypt", as you can see there are many numbers with .(xxxxxx))

Comment: I presses that dot and got a popup "Cut | Copy | Define | Share". What software are you using?

Comment: where is this code from?

Comment: 1. I use JustDecompile 2. It's WarGods anti-cheat (http://www.wargods.ro/wcd/download.php) - I need to get the cheat list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like obfuscated .net code. It also looks like that some names of properties/classes are obfuscated into some kind of unicode/other-non-readable representation, and your ".(724942833)" is actually "some_unreadable_symbol.some_probably_other_unreadable_symbol(724942833)".

Unreadable symbols should lead to classes and methods which will allow to understand what exactly happens there.
In order to make this mess readable you should rename these methods/classes into readable form. Did you try [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) ? According to its features list it should solve this problem instantly.